# How to avoid concurrent sessions per user in a spring-boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

a spring-boot application with REST APIs has Login API generates token using JWT
but a user can login multiple times
how can I avoid this scenario?

I tried the following configurations with no luck

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
                .expiredUrl("/login?expired")
                .and()
            .sessionFixation()
                .migrateSession();
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any JWT authentication in your configuration. There is only a form login, no JWT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation says](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/session-management.html#ns-concurrent-sessions) that you have to publish the following bean:

```java
@Bean
public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
}
```

Have you tried that?